# Rename data from Oracle Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to rename certain data from an oracle table. Lets assume the data in table "Random Items" has the form

```
Day      Item      Total

12/3     102         12

12/3     423         28 

12/4     102         48
```

I would like to rename the Item number to a specific string so when I grab the data from the table the output will look like

```
Day      Item           Total

12/3     Shoe           12

12/3     Orange         28 

12/4     Shoe           48
```

so Shoe = 102 and Orange = 423

I have no writing writes to the tables. I've looked at commands such as rename, synonym and replace but they all rename a specific table or column. I would like to reverence the data in the table.

Thank you

Comment: have you considered looking into decode/case functions ?

Comment: Are you trying to change the data that is physically stored in the table?  Or are you trying to present the data in a more user-friendly format?  Where are you getting the mappings that allow you to translate the number 102 to the string "Orange"?  Is there an `ITEM` table that stores that mapping?

Comment: I agree with @Justin, a table ITEM will also make your code so much more flexible - suppose you add a new item, you don't want to be changing code if you can change data.

Comment: @Justin Cave - I am not trying to change the data just a more user friendly way of displaying it. For this specific one there isn't an ITEM table to map 102 to "Orange" since they didn't create it. But there will be another separate piece of data that I do have such a reverence table for.Would it be possible (I assume it will) to use a reverence table to map the Items?

Comment: @Satya - I did not.Im prety new to oracle and its prety much a on the job training so far. I was googling but could only find results for table name changes. Thanks to the response of Ertunç and grimaldo I now know about them.

Comment: I assume you mean a "reference table" not a "reverence table".  Will that reference table map the numeric item number to the item name?  If so, then yes, you'd want to join that reference table to the "random items" table in order to provide the mapping.

Comment: no issues , glad that I could add something

Comment: @ Justin Cave (yes reference) Yes that is correct. Could you please provide me with a command just pointing me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using decode like:

```
select day, decode(item, '102', 'Shoe', '423', 'Orange',...), total from items
```

Comment: Talking about Oracle engine decode could be a kind of Case, but here's a nice document about the differences using Case and Decode functions. http://psoug.org/reference/decode_case.html

Answer (score 3):

```
select day, case ITEM when 102 then 'shoe'
                    when 423 then 'orange'
        end itemname, total
from items
```

Comment: ITEM is the field name 102 is the value in database and 'shoe' is the label you want to display. For further google for mysql case statement

Comment: Sorry I didn't want to post it, was a miss click. Was in the process of googling it. Thanks any case, I got it working using 

select day,
case
  when ITEM = 102 then 'shoe'
  when ITEM = 423 then 'orange'
end,
total
from items

Will this be the 'better' way of handling such a query or is grimaldo way better ?

Comment: grimaldo's suggestion is specific to oracle cause it utilizes **decode**. Mine is more general, but I only tested it on mysql. have a look at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac3a1/8). You can try different sql engines there. However in both cases the item list must be fixed. If the list is too long or generic, totally different solution is needed